# joining first name and last name in array

Tags: c#, arrays

i want to join the first name and last name in text file of c# , but just in one content with 15 first name and 15 last name , like this , and must be sort by alphabelt either by first name or last name

```
emily
adrian 
camille
lim
ong
ang
```

if first theт output must be if it is by first name

```
adrian ong  
camille ang
emily lim
```

if last

```
Ang camille
lim emily
ong adrian
```

Comment: I suppose you may use Enumerable.Range but let's see your code first. And please RTFM! http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you share a few records from the text file? The question is very confusing.

Comment: Come on. `File.ReadAllLines`, `string[]` array and a `for` loop is all you need to get it done. Don't ask for code, try writing it and come back when you face problems. but **try solving the problem first!**.

Comment: How will you know it's the start of LastName? by dividing the lines to two?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek how can i try it?? , i'm just a student , still studying , how can i know what to do if i even don't know what to put in code, and i'm a not a english speaker , forgive my grammar error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following provides the desired output and lets you control first or last name through a boolean flag you could tie into a parameter or to some input. Here is the .NET fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/bHuOWQ

```
using System;
using System.Linq; // Utilizing linq to perform sorting
using System.Collections.Generic; // Utilizing generic List to accumulate objects

// Statically provide sample data, but should use File.ReadAllLines when loading from file
string[] records = new string[] { //File.ReadAllLines to get from the file
    "emily",
    "adrian",
    "camille",
    "lim",
    "ong",
    "ang"
};

bool sortByFirstName = true; // Set to false if by last name
int range = records.Length / 2; // Since source data splits first and last names into same list, use value to define split between where first name stops and last name starts
var items = new List<string>(); // Define list to contain the sortable items 

// Iterate through the first and last names to gather the sortable names
for (int i = 0; i < range; i++)
{
    if (sortByFirstName == true) // If sorting by first name, format entry as "first last"
        items.Add(string.Format("{0} {1}", records[i], records[i+range]));
    else // Otherwise, sort by last name, format entry as "last first"
        items.Add(string.Format("{1} {0}", records[i], records[i+range]));
}
var sortedItems = items.OrderBy(s => s); // Use Linq to perform sorting
foreach (var s in sortedItems)
    Console.WriteLine(s); // Output the results
```

Yields:

```
adrian ong
camille ang
emily lim
```

Comment: Downvote for helping with no technical issue with the answer - really? Philosophical differences...

Comment: Added comments as requested by comments

Comment: That's better. And yes, voting is indeed a philosophical issue - there aren't official guidelines for it.

Comment: i want it from textfile , can it be?

Comment: Yes, you would use the File.ReadAllLines (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx) to pass in a filename and assign to the `records` variable.

Comment: @JasonW can you do the code? i still not know where to put it